# How to cite/reference code from Mathematica.StackExchange contributors, e.g. in a package I write?

Tags: discussion

I think the title is self explanatory, but I will try to *qualify* the question with the following addition i.e. do I need to include in my package(s) a reference to an appropriate license along with the credit to different contributors of code?

The motivation of the question is the desire to give credit where is due and obviously to not permit my code to be hijacked by whoever might find it profitable, again, without giving proper recognition to the original contributors.

Comment: citing in a package is a different matter than in a joirnal, but i do think this should be moved to meta

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1), particularly the section on "What is reasonable attribution?"

Comment: the biq question to me is the ambiguous block at the bottom `But what is code`.   Surely we don't need to give attribution every time exercising a technique learned by example here.

Comment: @JasonB: yep, got it! Thanx!

Comment: @george2079: if someone implemented eg an AVL tree I got to use, then I would want to give them credit. Also, if I implemented eg an AVL tree that I read about on SE, then I don't think I should give credit. Sounds fair enough and by the book?